# Prove [(q ˄ (p ↔ ¬ q) ) → q] is a tautology using logic laws

Tags: propositional-calculus

How to prove that this statement is tautology using logic laws

```
(q ˄ (p ↔ ¬ q) ) → q
```

Edit:

I got stuck here after trying to apply De Morgan's law:

```
(q ˄ (p ↔ ¬ q)) → q
¬ [q ˄ (p ↔ ¬ q)] ˅ q
¬ q ˅ ¬ (p ↔ ¬ q) ˅ q
¬ q ˅ (¬ p ↔ q) ˅ q
¬ q ˅ [(¬ p → q) ˄ (q → ¬ p)] ˄ q
```

Comment: When you say "logic laws" what laws exactly are you referring to? Depending on what laws you can you, you may or may not be able to prove the statement.

Comment: You can try at least to use the symbols consistently ...

Comment: (comment retracted)

Comment: But what's to prove? $(q \land r)\to q$ is a tautology, for any $r$.

Comment: It is not necessary to "unpack" $↔$; using *commutativity* and *associativity*, you can rewrite the fourth line as : $(¬ q \lor q) \lor  [¬ (p ↔ ¬ q)]$ and then apply $a \lor \lnot a \equiv T$ and $T \lor a \equiv T$ to conclude that the formula is equivalent to $TRUE$, i.e. a *tautology*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

You have to use the equivalence between $a \to b$ and $\lnot a \lor b$.

It must be :

> $(q \land (p \leftrightarrow ¬ q) ) \to q$

is equivalent to :

> > $\lnot [q \land (p \leftrightarrow ¬ q) ] \lor q$.

Then, apply [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to get :

> $\lnot q \lor \lnot (p \leftrightarrow ¬ q) \lor q$.

Now it is quite easy ... (see [Table of Logical Equivalences](http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf))

Comment: I have edited my post. can you check what's wrong ? and if it's right how can i continue/simplify the last statement?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The desired tautology has the form $(q\wedge r)\rightarrow q$

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on which logic laws you're allowed to do.

If you have the axiom schema $\phi\land\psi\rightarrow\phi$ it follows by substituting $q$ for $\phi$ and $(p \leftrightarrow \neg q)$ for $\psi$.

If on the other hand you're allowed to use truth tables, then it's just a matter of making a truth table and see it to be a tautology.